# Unable to create SDL thread with multi file program

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm having a problem with SDL threads so I made a little multi file code so it will be easier to show my problem

Header file

```
#ifndef MAINC_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINC_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <CONIO.H>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_thread.h>
using namespace std;
class mainc
{
    private:
        SDL_Thread* thread;
        int threadR;
        int testN=10;
    public:
        int threadF(void *ptr);
        int OnExecute();
        bool start();
};
#endif
```

One file

```
#include "mainc.h"
bool mainc::start() {
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    return false;
}
getch();
if(SDL_CreateThread(threadF, "TestThread", (void *)NULL)==NULL){
return false;
}
return true;
}

int mainc::threadF(void *ptr){
cout<<"This is a thread and here is a number: "<<testN<<endl;
return testN;
}
```

Second file

```
#include "mainc.h"

int mainc::OnExecute() {
    if(!start())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_WaitThread(thread,&threadR);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    mainc game;

    return game.OnExecute();
}
```

When I compile this I get this error

```
cannot convert 'mainc::threadF' from type 'int (mainc::)(void*)' to type 'SDL_ThreadFunction {aka int (*)(void*)}'
```

I dug around a bit and I found a solution but it gave me other errors I needed to make threadF static but I couldn't access any variables it gave me this error

```
invalid use of member 'mainc::testN' in static member function
```

But if I remove the variable from the function it runs fine
Now I don't know what do to because in my game I need to share variables which change

Comment: Member function pointers are not function pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testN is neither a static nor a public property of class mainc and to do what you're trying to do, it needs to be either.
If you want to use members of class "mainc" from within another thread body, you need to pass a pointer to an object of class "mainc" to SDL_CreateThread:

```
// ...
SDL_CreateThread(threadF, "TestThread", this)
// ...
```

and then

```
int mainc::threadF(void *ptr)
{
   mainc* myMainc = (mainc*)ptr;
   myMainc->testN; // now you can use it as you need
}
```

Beware of the encapsulation, though (testN is actually private)

Comment: Thank you it worked but is there any way to replace the myMainc->testN; to just testN; because it will take me some time to get used to it.

Comment: You can call a public class method within the thread body, making it the thread body instead.